# Conflict occuring in Jquery datepicker with other existing Jquery code

Tags: jquery, conflict, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am a beginner nearing completion of my project. I have added this datepicker from JqueryUI as my requirement is that only "Sunday" should be disabled and date should be restricted from tomorrow to next 10 days. I tried using other datepickers but none worked.
Then I tried implementing it with a part of the code and figured out that when I commented this line

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The datepicker worked just fine! but without the above line my page won't function properly.
The rest of my date picker code is as follows.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-dp.css" />
 <script src="js/jquery-dp-1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-dp-2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
 <script>
     $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1, 
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
     maxDate: "+0M +10D",
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                 var day = date.getDay();
                 return [(day != 0), ''];
             }
 });
});
</script>
```

So now what should I do to make sure my page runs smoothly along with the datepicker.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A tip and a possible solution: try to put the <script> tags before the </body> tag and the stylesheets inside the <head> tag . Also, make sure that jQuery is being loaded first before it loads the DatePicker by putting it above the datepicker.js script tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this in your JQuery script.

```
$.noConflict();  //Not to conflict with other scripts
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1, 
                dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
                maxDate: "+0M +10D",
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0), ''];
}
});

});
```

Comment: It is executing without a conflict, but can you provide explanation?

Comment: noConflict is a jQuery function https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/, your datepicker is possibly conflicting with another datepicker, perhaps bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Just arrange both the files in proper sequence and my problem is solved.

1 ) jquery-ui.min.js
2 ) bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).